# How to save presets in light room?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

I have gave effects in one image in light room software.. now I want to save effects..please let me know how to save presets in light room...

Comment: GD.SE is not a tech support site and your question is not about graphic design, thus off-topic here.

Comment: Hi itsmedesigner, [Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Answer (score 1):

...On the preset menu is a button that looks like a plus symbol. Press it and you can save your settings as a preset:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try this!! n ya why I got negative points on this question?

Comment: @itsmedesigner your question is very basic and probably could've been solved by looking in the help or on Google faster than it took to ask on here. People generally consider that lazy on here and downvote. Can see our [tour] for more information